# How can I combine this array of HTML elements into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently react highlight tools work based off of a string sequence within a sentence. IE highlight the word `quick` in `the quick fox`. This is fine however would not work if quick was repeated multiple times.

I'm building a highlight tool based off of insecticides. This works by spitting the sentence into an array of characters and inserting `<span highlight>` and `</span` around the selected word like so

Original

```
 0: t
 1: h
 2: e
 3: 

 4: q
 5: u
 6: i
 7: c
 8: k
 9: 
10: f
11: o
12: x
```

After inserting a highlight for quick at 4, 8

```
 0: t
 1: h
 2: e
 3: 
 4: <span highlight>
 6: q
 7: u
 8: i
 9: c
10: k
11: </span>
12: 
13: f
14: o
15: x
```

and then joining them back together to form `the <span highlight>quick</span> fox`

However I have to add those `span`'s as a string otherwise they would not join together correctly, this causes them to lose there reactness.

Does anyone know how I might combine this array so that it works with react as in, the onClick method will work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. See the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

`class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const markup = 'the <span highlight>quick</span> fox';
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markup }} />;
  }
}`

Comment: Sorry I should've made it more clear in the answer but onClick does not seem to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be combined to `render` each `word` of a `sentence` *conditionally*.

The [`regex pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) [`\s`](https://regexr.com/3q6ln) matches `whitespace characters`.

See below below for a practical example

See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n4jqonovj) for more context.

```js
// Style.
const style = {
  display: 'inline-block',
  margin: "10px"
}

// Highlight.
class Highlight extends React.Component {

  // State
  state = {
    sentence: "The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    target: false
  }

  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <div>
      {this.state.sentence.split(/\s/).map(word => {
        const hightlight = (word === this.state.target)
        const onClick = () => this.setState({target: word})
        return <Word word={word} highlight={hightlight} onClick={onClick}/>
      })}
    </div>
  )
  
}

// Word.
const Word = ({highlight, word, onClick}) => highlight ?
  <span style={style}><i>{word}</i></span> :
  <button onClick={onClick} style={style}>{word}</button>


// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<Highlight/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```